# Passing the NFC tag id (hex String) to another activity on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

So currently I am working on an android app that read a NFC tag ID and pass that ID to another activity to be worked on. However, the tag ID seems to be null when it has been passed to the second activity.

Here is some of my code relating to the issue

```
         public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), test.class);

                TextView octopus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.octopus);
        //store the tag id into a TextView      
  octopus.setText(ByteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)));

    //Get the String from the TextView and pass on to the test.class

                String octopusID = octopus.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra("octopusID", octopusID);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        }

        private String ByteArrayToHexString(byte [] inarray) {
            int i, j, in;
            String [] hex = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
            String out= "";

            for(j = 0 ; j < inarray.length ; ++j)
            {
                in = (int) inarray[j] & 0xff;
                i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
                out += hex[i];
                i = in & 0x0f;
                out += hex[i];
            }
                return out;
            }
    }
```

The second activity is a simple activity for testing purpose

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView test;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String octopusID = intent.getStringExtra("octopusID");


        test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
        test.setText(octopusID);
    }
}
```

The xml for the second activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.petrecord.user.petrecord.test">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

For some reasons, the TextView with the id: test on the second activity always display nothing when a tag is discovered. The TextView with the id: octopus will always display the tag ID when it read a NFC tag so I am assuming the NFC tag reading function is working but somehow the string is lost through passing onto the second activity. I have used the same code for passing variables through different activities in my other project and they worked fine so I am really not sure what is happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are using the intent with the name "i" to start the second activity but you are setting your data on the intent with the name "intent"

Comment: @tobifasc so the intent name of the two activities need to be the same?

Comment: no. just take a closer look. you are using  `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), test.class);` to create your intent in the first activity and `startActivity(i);` to send that intent. so if you want to pass a string to that activity you have to use `i.putExtra("octopusID", octopusID);` and not `intent.putExtra("octopusID", octopusID);`

Comment: @tobifasc I get it now. It was a very newbie mistake. But It still shows nothing on the second activity after I changed the intent to i.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you obviously need to address the issue identified by tobifasc in that you're not passing the data in the first place:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), test.class);
TextView octopus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.octopus);
// ... ommited ...
String octopusID = octopus.getText().toString();

//intent.putExtra("octopusID", octopusID);
i.putExtra("octopusID", octopusID);
startActivity(i);
```

But you could simplify the above code and I think this might address the other issue you reported. Why bother with this line `String octopusID = octopus.getText().toString();` when you already have the TagID in `ByteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID))`?

I would recommend you do:

```
String uidHex = ByteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID));
// other code goes here
octopus.setText(uidHex);
i.putExtra("uidHex", uidHex);
// now pass intent to new activity
```

That should work